# Unsupported object type int Error where array is already in float32

Tags: keras, tensorflow, numpy

I am learning DL. For the following dataset::  spam.csv can be found here::[Click here to see](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ula90nHxigsxsqvyu1zuY-mPYOQB2VOO/view?usp=share_link). I am trying to implement a simple NN to detect spam email. For the following code::

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Z ML Lab/data/naive/spam.csv')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Message')
df = df.reset_index()
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df.Category[i]=='ham':
        df.Category[i]=0
    else:
        df.Category[i]=1
X = df.Message
y = df.Category
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X_vected = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X_vected,y,test_size=0.2)
X_train = np.asarray(X_train.toarray()).astype(np.float32)
X_test = np.asarray(X_test.toarray()).astype(np.float32)
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(100,input_shape=(8709,),activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=5)
```

Here, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-533-dae2432e1f5b> in <module>
      5 ])
      6 model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
----> 7 model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=5)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    100       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    101   ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 102   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    103 
    104 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

It says Unsupported object type int. However, I clearly converted it to float32. I don't think I need to convert y_train as well (however, I converted it as well, and faced several other errors). I searched and tried all different approaches such as finding out if there are any null values in X_train, if X_train contains any object type, and different ways to convert to float32, none of these worked for me. Please help. Thanks a lot.